# Dojo xhrGet only returning null

Tags: javascript, dojo

The following Dojo code's load callback returns null. There shouldn't be any problem because jQuery's ajax works fine. What am I missing here?

**Dojo version - doesn't work**

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url:"http://localhost:11039/",
    handleAs:"json",
    load: function(data){
        console.log(data); // Prints null
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }
});
```

**jQuery version - works**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:11039/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res) // Prints some JSON
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    }
});
```

Looking at Firebugs net tab I notice that the jQuery version is in fact sending a GET request:

```
GET localhost:11039    200OK     localhost:11039     62.8KB
```

while the Dojo version... "OPTIONS"?

```
OPTIONS localhost:11039    200OK     localhost:11039     62.8KB
```

**Additional Details:**

- I get the same result in Ffox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: i could not see any major error, but can you try giving a relative url.

Comment: it's wired. Not sure why dojo used a HTTP OPTIONS instead of HTTP GET. Do you have a working url to test?

Comment: I was mistaken in my second bullet. I was under the impression that sub domains didn't fall into the cross domain issue. My node.js app (where I was sending the get request) was on api.nodenews.chris... and my dojo page was on nodenews.chris...). Still not sure why localhost won't work. It's frustrating because jQuery just does. Work that is...

Comment: Different port numbers are also considered cross domain. Are both the jQuery and Dojo scripts served from localhost:11039?

Comment: @j33r Did you resolve this? Great if you can share the answer with us.. because if it does work in jQuery, that's intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo sending an OPTIONS request usually means dojo considers it a cross-domain request.

The OPTIONS request is checking for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to see if the request should be performed, even though it is considered cross-domain.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control for more details